# Редирект в Kohana Framework

Tags: redirect, редирект, php, kohana

Всем привет!
На сайте есть ссылка заглушка на которой предлагается скачать мобильное приложение.
Ссылка к примеру такая sitename.ru/share/

Так вот, задача состоит в том, что к примеру юзер переходит по ссылке sitename.ru/share/places/20 и его должно редиректнуть на сайт заглушку sitename.ru/share/

Надеюсь правильно объяснил суть, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Вы наткнулись на какую-то проблему или пока не пытались искать решение сами?

Comment: Искал, пол интернета перекапал пока не решил.
Нужно как то пробросить редирект вот ума не приложу как.

Comment: Да, бывает - тема редкая. А версия Kohana какая?

Comment: Версия 3.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Спасибо, редирект работает, но как мне его прикрутить к sitename.ru/share/place/22

Повесьте на роут:

```
Route::set('share', 'share(/<action>(/<id>))')
  ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'share',
    'action' => 'places',
    'id'    => '\d',
));
```

Теперь все запросы, обращающиеся к `share/<action>/<id>` обрабатываются одним контроллером Share, в котором достаточно задать action_places() и с этого метода уже делать redirect, как показал xEdelweiss.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!!!
Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: @kemerov4anin, если мне не изменяет память, то:

    Route::set('share', 'share(/<action>(/<id>))', array('id' => '\d'))...

а не в ``defaults``

Comment: да. Каюсь. Ошибся.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда вот вам сия нелогичная конструкция:

```
$this->redirect('/share');
```

Comment: Спасибо, редирект работает, но как мне его прикрутить к sitename.ru/share/place/22

Answer (score 1):

В `bootstrap.php`. Добавь, только роуты пропиши до файла

```
 Route::set('contacts', 'contacts')   
 ->defaults(array( 
         'directory'  => 'index', 
         'controller' => 'page', 
         'action'     => 'contacts', 
 ));
```